# How to pass values from one class to another class using wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to pass values from one class file to another class.

E.g:

**Step1:**

Class1.cs

```
public class Class1
    {
        public string LogedInPerson { get; set; }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.LogedInPerson; }
            set { this.LogedInPerson = value; }
        }
    }
```

**Step2:**

Value has been assigned in below method:

test.xaml.cs

```
public void assignValue()
{
     Class1 obj = new Class1();
     obj.LogedInPerson = "test123";
}
```

**Step3:**

I would like to get "test123" values from Class2.cs.

E.g:

```
public void test()
        {
            string selected_dept = ?? //How to get "test123" from here.
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have variables class that includes public variables. Define instance of `class1` in variables class .

```
public static class1 myclass=new class1();
```

in test.xml.cs set value

```
public void assignValue()
{
 myclass.LogedInPerson = "test123";
}
```

in class2.cs

```
public void test()
    {
        string selected_dept = myclass.LogedInPerson;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `Class1` outside `assignValue()` methos

```
Class1 obj = new Class1();

public void assignValue()
{

     obj.LogedInPerson = "test123";
}
public string returnValue()
{

  return obj.LogedInPerson;
}
```

if your second class name `test.xaml` then call it like this, but I don't think you can use class name `test.xaml` so use a nice name instead there eg: `Class2`

```
public void test()
{
    test.xaml test = new test.xaml();
    test.assignValue();
    string selected_dept = test.returnValue(); //How to get "test123" from here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question is more on the topic of basic Object Oriented Programming principles, not so much about WPF specific features. Therefore, I will provide you a non-WPF specific answer, as it will allow me to address your question in the most direct way.

In OOP, a method can return a result to the caller. So, for instance,

```
public string GetReturnObject(){

     return "This is a return object";

}
```

You can create a new object and pass it back to the caller,

```
public void Test(){

     string data = GetReturnObject(); 

}
```

And now `data` will be assigned the object that was returned from the method that `Test()` called. So, if you modify your `AssignValue` method by adding a return type and passing the instantiated `Class1` object back to the caller, you will have the answer you need

```
public Class1 assignValue()
{
     Class1 obj = new Class1();
     obj.LogedInPerson = "test123";
     return obj;
}
```

Hope that helps.